# What items are farmable in Valheim?

Tags: valheim

We have found multiple seeds for vegetables, like carrots and turnips, but are there other seed-based plants that can be planted and farmed?

Comment: Onions too. There's a very useful wiki over at https://valheim.fandom.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 4 major crops you can currently farm in Valheim, you have already mentioned two.

The other two are [Barley](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Barley) and [Flax](https://valheim.fandom.com/wiki/Flax).  Both of these can only be grown in the plains biome, however.

There are also other plantable seeds that are not considered crops.  Namely the ones that drop from trees (Beech, Pine, Fir and Birch).  Oak trees do not drop seeds currently.

Comment: biome specific farming? yikes

Comment: You can grow mushrooms in the Mistlands now and birch and oak drop seeds and acorns to plant and farm.